# RichFaces 4.x, is it possible to attach one rich:dataScroller component to different tables?

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

In RichFaces 4.x, the documentation showcase say : "no additional updating is required in order to synchronize different rich:dataScroller components attached to the same table".
Well i want to do the inverse ...

I mean I have two tables : Patients and Samples.
In my interface, for a set of Patients displayed in table Patient i have a set of samples associated & displayed in an another table called Sample.
I use a query who fetches the data with the preRenderView and listener stuff(i'm sure you know what i mean)...As a consequence I instantiate my two lists ,Patients & Samples (they have a relationship 1:n in the database schema).
I they are not empty I showed the tables in a View Scope thanks to ajaxRendered...

I want to navigate in table Participant with a rich:dataScroller Component.
Each time the displayed content of Participant change(Go next page...), the samples associated in table Samples should change too(move to associate samples).

Is it possible to do that of one way or another ?

Thanks.

Comment: Forget about that, I'll make things more complicated. For what you want to achieve you have to: trigger an ajax event when a participant is selected -> Update the samples table model in your managed bean with the ones corresponding to the participant -> update your samples datatable.

Comment: Yep Ok. That's what i'm also doing actually but i was wondering if i could do something more with the rich:dataScroller...Clearly not.I have to re-think about the user-interface to avoid the problem.Ok Thanks again Xtreme Biker ^^